# Incorrect spacing for > and < when using newtxmath and bigdelims option

Tags: spacing, newtxmath

I am using the `newtxmath` package with the `bigdelims` option recommended by the package documentation.  Curiously, this combination appears to produce no spacing around `<` and `>` (but correct spacing for `\leq` and `\geq`).  When I remove the `bigdelims` option, the spacing is corrected.

Is this a bug in `newtxmath`, or is there another option that I must provide?

Here is a minimal example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bigdelims]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
$j > i$ and $j \geq i$ and $i < j$ and $i \leq j$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting any suspicious-looking output. Is your TeX distro up to date? Could you edit your question to post a screenshot of the output you're getting?

Comment: Looks fine here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42709342/tx.png

Comment: @Sigur: No worries, but you might be interested in [How can I upload an image to be included in a comment?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4290/5764) (to avoid dead links in the future).

Comment: @Jubobs @Sigur I've added a picture of the output that I get.  
Thanks for the pointer; I will check that my copy of `newtxmath` is up to date.

Comment: @Jubobs: I get the same out as the OP: the `\ge` and `\leq` are fine, but the `>` and `<` are not.  BTW, I haven not updated my TeXLive 2013 distribution a while.

Comment: @PeterGrill Curious. I get proper spacing for all the operators used in the MWE.

Comment: @Jubobs: I have `newtxmath.sty 2013/11/19 v1.16`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I have `newtxmath 2014/03/11 v1.24`. Perhaps it's a bug that was fixed in the latest (fairly recent) release.

Comment: @Jubobs: Sure seems that way. I just updated to the latest version `newtxmath.sty    2014/03/11 v1.24` and things appear fine with the above MWE.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, I updated my `newtx` and I get the correct spacing for `>` and `<`.  Thanks for your help.  Do you want to turn your comment into an answer, or should I vote to close this question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it stems from a bug that was corrected in a more recent version of `newtxmath` than the OP was originally using.